# How to create a reference/bibliography in LaTeX?

Tags: biblatex, bibtex, bibliographies

I'm new to LaTeX and I was given a rather complex template to use, I'm having trouble to add a reference/bibliography. I'm using Windows 8.1, Miktex for 64 bit and TexStudio. I have the following line in the template preamble:

```
\usepackage[backend=bibtex,natbib=true,sorting=none,sortcites]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{references.bib}
```

I've read people use EITHER `bibtex` or `biblatex` to add bibliography to a document, whatever those are, but this line includes both `bibtex` and `biblatex`. I've created a `reference.bib` file in the same directory as the `main.tex` file. The template also has following line near the end and it's giving me "empty bibliography" error.

```
\printbibliography[heading=bibliography,title={Ном зүй}]
```

Also, whenever I build the file I get the following warning:

```
Using fall-back Bibtex(8) backend:(biblatex) functionality maybe reduced/unavailable.
```

in the `blx-bibtex.def` file.

And here is my `references.bib` file's content, it's just a dummy value, I'm not even sure if its syntax is correct

```
@BOOK{DUMMY:1,
AUTHOR="John Doe",
TITLE="The Book without Title",
PUBLISHER="Dummy Publisher",
YEAR="2100",
}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! For the last part of your question, have a look at this https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/365075/117534, so it's nothing to worry about if you're intending to use Bibtex as a backend. Have a look at [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/299286/117534) to get a better understanding of the difference between Bibtex and biblatex (they're different things).

Comment: Welcome. *"I'm new to LaTeX and I was given a rather complex template to use,"* This is the worst start you can get. You need to know the basics first. Use the minimal example [from here](https://github.com/johannesbottcher/MDT-Quick-Manual/blob/master/bibTest.tex), read [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63852/question-mark-or-bold-citation-key-instead-of-citation-number) and make a bibliography with the minimal test file. Once that works, go back to your complex template. Or rather use a [minimal template](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Scientific_Reports).

Comment: You can also have a look at [bibliographies with biblatex and biber](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Bibliographies_with_biblatex_and_biber)

Comment: I'm sorry, but I was given a very specific template, that's why I just can't use minimal/simple example

Comment: Ok, I think I figured it out, I changed the backend to biber and I had to use the command /cite, but I'm developing and android app for undergraduate project and using latex for it's documentation, I had a lot of help from stackexchange community when writing the app's code, but the code itself is not part of the documentation, which means I don't have to actually use the /cite command, what I need is to just list the websites I browsed in the bibliograpy, in general

Comment: If you use the template or not is your decision. But did you get the minimal test file to run? If not, there is no point in looking further into this.

Comment: For the warning put `backend=biber` instead of `backend=bibtex`.