# fall-back BibTeX(8) backend: (biblatex)functionality may be reduced/unavailable

Tags: biblatex, bibtex

```
/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/blx-bibtex.def:
Package biblatex Warning: Using fall-back BibTeX(8) backend:
(biblatex)                functionality may be reduced/unavailable.
```

EXAMPLE:

```
\usepackage[backend=bibtex,style=authoryear,natbib=true]{biblatex} 

\addbibresource{Elyssesbib.bib}

\usepackage[autostyle=true]{csquotes} 

\begin{document}
\...... rest of doc.
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! It's just a warning: to have access to all the functionalities of `biblatex`, use `biber` as a backend, not `bibtex8`.

Comment: You can simply ignore the warning and go on using BibTeX. But that is not recommended, you should try and switch over to Biber ([Biblatex with Biber: Configuring my editor to avoid undefined citations](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864), [bibtex vs. biber and biblatex vs. natbib](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/25701/35864)). Only Biber supports the full set of `biblatex` features. BibTeX is supposed to be used only in legacy documents and if absolutely necessary. That said, if everything works fine for you at the moment, you don't have to change.

Comment: See also [Warning: “Using fall-back BibTeX(8) backend:(biblatex) functionality may be reduced/unavailable.”](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/365060/35864)