# How to avoid undefined citations with biber

Tags: bibtex, cross-referencing, compiling, biber

I start with this script:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{bibtextest.bib}
\begin{document}
See \cite{somebook}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

with bibtextbib.bib:

```
@book{somebook,
      author        = "Some author",
      publisher     = "Publisher",
      title         = "{Title}",
      year          = "1997",
}
```

It compiles fine with the output:

[image]

However, I see a warning:

```
Package biblatex Warning: Using fall-back BibTeX(8) backend:
(biblatex)                functionality may be reduced/unavailable.
```

[Warning: "Using fall-back BibTeX(8) backend:(biblatex) functionality may be reduced/unavailable."](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/365060/warning-using-fall-back-bibtex8-backendbiblatex-functionality-may-be-redu) suggests me to experiment by replacing `backend=bibtex` with `backend=biber`. However, this leads to undefined references:

[image]

[Biblatex with Biber: Configuring my editor to avoid undefined citations](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/154751/biblatex-with-biber-configuring-my-editor-to-avoid-undefined-citations?noredirect=1&lq=1) is not helpful as I compile by command line arguments `pdflatex`/`xelatex` and `bibtex`.

How to avoid undefined references with biber compiling from the command line?

Comment: You need to run biber instead of bibtex if you change the backend.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, using biber I experience this problem `INFO - This is Biber 2.9
INFO - Logfile is 'bibtextest.blg'
INFO - Reading 'bibtextest.bcf'
ERROR - Error: Found biblatex control file version 3.5, expected version 3.4.
This means that your biber (2.9) and biblatex (3.12) versions are incompatible.
See compat matrix in biblatex or biber PDF documentation.
INFO - ERRORS: 1`

Comment: Update your TeX distribution (https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/55437/35864). As the message states your `biblatex` and Biber versions don't match. What TeX system and OS are you running? Remember that if you use MikTeX you will probably have to run the update in Admin *and* User mode.

Comment: Judging by https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/516788/35864 you managed to get things going here. Do you want an answer you can accept or can this be closed as a duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852/35864 or https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/55437/35864?

Comment: @moewe better to produce an answer for someone who compiles from the command line and has incompatible version of `biber` and `biblatex`.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Do you want to type up a quick answer here, please?

Comment: @moewe, I use Ubuntu 18.04 and TexLive 2018

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I went ahead and wrote a short answer so this question can be marked as answered. If you would like to write an answer now, please give me a ping and I'll remove my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `backend=biber,` instead of `backend=bibtex,` you need to run Biber on your document and not BibTeX. Assuming that your document is called `doc.tex` you would now run

```
pdflatex doc
biber doc
pdflatex doc
pdflatex doc
```

instead of `pdflatex doc`, `bibtex doc`, `pdflatex doc`, `pdflatex doc`. (Where `pdflatex` can of course be replaced by your favourite flavour of LaTeX: `latex`, `lualatex`, `xelatex`.).

A common error one gets when running BibTeX instead of Biber is

```
This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (MiKTeX 2.9.7250 64-bit)
The top-level auxiliary file: doc.aux
I found no \citation commands---while reading file doc.aux
I found no \bibdata command---while reading file doc.aux
I found no \bibstyle command---while reading file doc.aux
(There were 3 error messages)
```

---

The error

```
ERROR - Error: Found biblatex control file version 3.5, expected version 3.4.
        This means that your biber (2.9) and biblatex (3.12) versions are incompatible.
```

means exactly what it says: The installed Biber and `biblatex` versions are incompatible. Remove all temporary files (`.aux`, `.bbl`, `.bcf`, ...) and update your TeX system thoroughly and properly (see [How do I update my TeX distribution?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/55437/35864)).