# force biber/bibtex warnings when fields missing in entry types

Tags: biblatex, biber, warnings

Consider this example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{bibtextest.bib}
\begin{document}
See  \cite{bookentry}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

with `bibtextest.bib`:

```
@book{bookentry,
      title         = "{Title}",
      series        = "Technical Design Report",
      year          = "1997",
}
```

The entry `bookentry` is missing a required field `author` (p. 8 in http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf).

How can I force Biber to issue a warning along the lines of

```
Warning--empty author in bookentry
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can ask Biber to validate your `.bib` file with the option `--validate-datamodel`/`-V`.

If one runs Biber with

```
biber -V <filename>
```

for the example in the question one obtains

```
INFO - This is Biber 2.13
INFO - Logfile is 'warningsforbiber.blg'
INFO - Reading 'warningsforbiber.bcf'
INFO - Found 1 citekeys in bib section 0
INFO - Processing section 0
INFO - Globbing data source 'warningsforbiber.bib'
INFO - Globbed data source 'warningsforbiber.bib' to warningsforbiber.bib
INFO - Looking for bibtex format file 'warningsforbiber.bib' for section 0
INFO - LaTeX decoding ...
INFO - Found BibTeX data source 'warningsforbiber.bib'
INFO - Datamodel validation starting
WARN - Datamodel: Entry 'bookentry' (warningsforbiber.bib): Missing mandatory field 'author'
INFO - Datamodel validation complete
INFO - Overriding locale 'en-US' defaults 'normalization = NFD' with 'normalization = prenormalized'
INFO - Overriding locale 'en-US' defaults 'variable = shifted' with 'variable = non-ignorable'
INFO - Sorting list 'nty/global//global/global' of type 'entry' with template 'nty' and locale 'en-US'
INFO - No sort tailoring available for locale 'en-US'
INFO - Writing 'warningsforbiber.bbl' with encoding 'UTF-8'
INFO - Output to warningsforbiber.bbl
INFO - WARNINGS: 1
```