# biblatex/biber display warning if entry is missing for style

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, biber

Is there a flag/option that can be set for biber/biblatex so that one is notified if a field is missing for the selected

I think this should be found in `biblatex` since `biber` doesn't have information about the selected style and thus only can (and does) issue warnings on missing mandatory fields. But some styles require additional fields to be set.

The thing I'd like to avoid is that unnoticed the bibliography isn't uniform because some literature entries have attributes set that other didn't (which therefore are simply not printed).

I know there are posts here on similar topics but as far as I've found them they are only about `biber` warnings.

Comment: what should the difference between mandatory fields and additional mandatory fields? If a style requires some fields it can setup the datamodel for this.

Comment: Oh I didn't knew that styles can declare a Field mandatory, but even then there are Fields which are printetd if present and omitted when not, somehow I'd like so watch over this to check if something is missing (other than reading through the bibliography manually)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is true that the `biblatex` documentation roughly characterises certain fields as mandatory and others as optional, but that is a very loose description, which I would only interpret as saying that if you have all mandatory fields filled out, the entry should come out sensible in the bibliography and citations (with all standard styles).

In the `biblatex` world, data model verification is performed solely on the Biber side (via the `--validate-datamodel`/`-V` option, see e.g. [force biber/bibtex warnings when fields missing in entry types](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/516788/35864) and a more involved example with new constraints in [checking huge bibtex database for series and number and so on](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/582947/35864)). The LaTeX side of things passes all available and relevant data on to Biber (data model validation constraints are defined in the `.dbx` file, I'm not sure if and how strictly contributed styles set up data model verification). The relevant information isn't even available in a LaTeX-usable format, so the LaTeX side cannot really perform data model validation.

In theory it would be possibly to redefine the internal `biblatex` macros that print the field to issue a warning to the `.log` file that the field is missing (normally empty fields are just ignored). But many fields are not strictly speaking required for a good bibliography output and you would get many false positive warnings. So you would have to teach the LaTeX side of things about the data model constraints as well in order to suppress the false positives this would essentially duplicate all the effort already done for the Biber side. It would also be possible to add a simple test like

```
\AtEveryBibitem{%
  \iffieldundef{title}
    {\textbf{Warning! This entry has no title!}}
    {}%
}
```

but again, you'd have to manually code all the constraints yourself.